# Can you tell me why I'm getting a "string cannot be converted to int" error

Tags: java

I have an assignment which asks for everything I have in the code below. That all works fine - I just need to calculate any monthly hours over 160 hours to be paid at 1.5 times the normal hourly rate. My math seems sound and calculates fine:

((hours - 160) * overtime) + (160 * hourlyRate)

But I dont know if I'm putting this if statement in the right method or if it even should be an if statement. My increase/decreasePay methods are working prior to this and they need to stay. I removed some things so it's easier to read.

HourlyWorker Class:

```
public class HourlyWorker extends Employee
{
private int hours;
private double hourlyRate;
private double monthlyPay;
private double overtime = (1.5 * hourlyRate);

public HourlyWorker(String last, String first, String ID, double rate)
{
   super(last, first, ID);
   hourlyRate = rate;
}

public void setHours(int hours)
{
   this.hours = hours;
}

public int getHours()
{
   return hours;
}

public void setHourlyRate(double rate)
{
   this.hourlyRate = rate;
}

public double getHourlyRate()
{
   return hourlyRate;
}


public double getMonthlyPay()
{
   if (hours > 160)
   {
      monthlyPay = ((hours - 160) * overtime) + (160 * hourlyRate);
   }
   else 
   {
      monthlyPay = hourlyRate * hours;
   }
   return monthlyPay;
}

public void increasePay(double percentage)
{
   hourlyRate *= 1 + percentage / 100;
}

public void decreasePay(double percentage)
{
   hourlyRate *= 1 - percentage / 100;
}

}
```

What I'm testing with:

```
public class TestEmployee2
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
   Employee [] staff = new Employee[3];
      HourlyWorker hw1 = new HourlyWorker("Bee", "Busy", "BB1265", 10);
       
      hw1.setHours(200);    
      staff[0] = hw1;

   System.out.println(staff[0].getMonthlyPay());
   staff[0].increasePay(10);
   System.out.println(staff[0].getMonthlyPay());
}
}
Output is:
1600 (initial monthly rate, with 40 overtime hours and 160 regular hours)
1760 (10% increase to the monthlyPay)

Should be:
2006
22
```

06.6

Comment: In the method addArtist(), you are adding an Artist to the artists ArrayList using add(String, String). Unfortuntely there is no such method in ArrayList, and it thinks you're trying to use add(String, int). Please check the ArrayList documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @NomadMaker mentioned, the problem is in your `addArtist` method.
Your current method:

```java
   public void addArtist(String artistName, String genre)
   {
      this.artists.add(artist, genre); 
   }
```

Remember that `this.artists` is a list which can store Objects of type `Artist`.
Therefore you should create a new artist with the new parameters. Something like:

```java
public void addArtist(String artist, String genre)
   {
      this.artists.add(new Artist(artist, genre)); 
   }
```

As you might be guessing, you do not have a constructor of **Artist** with two parameters (should accept name, and genre). Therefore, you should add this constructor to your code:

```java
public Artist(String name, String genre) {
 this.name = name;
 this.genre = genre;
}
```

Error explanation:

`artists` is a list, what you are doing when calling `this.artist.add(artist, genre)` is calling a method which belongs to the list collection that has this signature: `add(int index, Artist artist)` the **index** will be the index to place the artist (if the order matters for you).